# Do Google TPU VMs get automatically deleted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

I'm currently using a TPU VM that I set up to use my TPU quotas for the TPU Research Cloud program. I tried SSHing into the VM earlier and encountered an unknown error. Upon refreshing the page the VM was deleted.

The TPU that I was using was a v4 TPU, and it's stated that v4 TPU VMs cannot be stopped and can only be deleted. My assumption is that when the resource was reclaimed or something by Google it may have gotten deleted due to this but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you happen to create a Preemptible TPU VM? If so, Google might preempt (shut down) these TPUs at any time, if it requires additional TPU resources. Also, check your audit log associated with the TPU instance.

Comment: I did create the TPU VM with the `--preemptible` flag set, so I'm assuming that they were shut down. I didn't know that this would completely delete the VM though. I read that v4 VMs cannot be stopped and only deleted. Is this why they're simply being deleted?

Comment: can you share the command you used to create the TPU VM? are you creating TPU vm or TPU node?

Comment: I'm creating a TPU VM because I also read that v4's cannot be created via nodes. The command I used is this: `gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm create trc-v4 --zone=us-central2-b --accelerator-type=v4-8 --version=tpu-vm-v4-pt-2.0 --preemptible`. The zone is one of the zones specified in my TRC welcome email.

Comment: ok, can you run this command to check the TPU instance status: `gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm list --zone=us-central2-b`? If the TPU is preempted, it should show status as `PREEMPTED`. If it can't find the instance, could be a glitch or some other activities. Better check the audit log from console.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud TPU VMs are not automatically deleted unless under specific circumstances. These might be the reasons why your TPU VM was deleted:

- It might have an inactive TPU quota. The TPU Cloud program might have quotas tied to TPU usage. If your VM wasn't used for a significant amount of time, Google might have reclaimed the resources to provide them to active users.
- Check the logs of your project as it's also possible that someone with the necessary permissions accidentally deleted the VM.

To avoid this in the future, check the TPU Cloud program documentation for specific policies on VM inactivity and quota usage. You might also want to contact Google Cloud support for further investigation into the cause of your VM deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using [On-demand quota type](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quota#quota_types) on your TPU VMs which is different with Reserved quotas. It means that even if you could request and be approved on the increase on your quota limit for Cloud TPU resources, the availability of resources is not guaranteed when you do not have reserved resources.